# Issue trying to use the polymer element wysiwyg-e

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

Have anyone use this element [wysiwyg-e](https://github.com/miztroh/wysiwyg-e)?

I'm very sure that the problem that I have is something that I don't know but I would like ask you for help, I installed the element via bower in my polymer project, all the installation went fine I don't got any error.

- After that I reference the component in the element.html:

  `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/wysiwyg-e/wysiwyg-e.html">`
- And after that I put the usage code in this page to test the
  component

When I refresh my website I got the following error in the console:

> polymer-mini.html:2061 Uncaught TypeError: tools[i]._setRange0 is not
>   a function

Please could you help me to find a solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Its good that you were able to resolve your issue without anyone's help. But in future please provide code along with issue for others to help.

Comment: I will add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I miss some references. Thanks